# Добавить условие проверки поля на "НЕ ПУСТО"

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи!

В своем приложении использую jQuery-плагин [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) ([перевод Jeditable на русский](http://it-route.ru/jeditable_manual_ru/)).

Необходимо добавить условие проверки, в случае если пытаются засабмитить пустое поле, т.е. поле очистили и нажимают на **ENTER**, надо сразу отобразить окно, что мол **"Поле не должно быть пустым!"**.

Вот [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/v6WVa/) просто пример. Может как-то можно добавить проверочку?

Comment: ваш пример не работает, потому-что вы взяли jeditable не из cdn а с какого-то левого места.

Comment: @eicto да вроде источник оригинальный:
* Project home:
 *   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
да и работает код как надо...!?

Comment: лучше с cdn брать, http://cdnjs.com офиц сайт это не cdn

Comment: @eicto [здесь вот][1] коллега потрудился, но по нажатию на ENTER ничего не происходит, а конкретно - не происходит отправка данных на сервер, поле остается редактируемым при снятии фокуса.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20223190/2795684

Comment: ага я доку и исходник уже посмотрел, там по-моему никак, т.к. если повесить функцию на blur, то сабмит не вызывается а что-то самому его непонятно как инициализировать

Comment: взять какой-нибудь другой плагин, либо пропатчить этот и сделать pull request, более подходящий, этот не очень-то гибкий.

Comment: @eicto [я справился :)][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/274936#275175

Comment: @eicto может подскажите как еще добавить проверку на текст, т.е. если ввели буквы или символы кроме цифр...?

Answer (score 1):

В общем и снова моя победила ) Если кому-то интересно решение см.ниже:

```
function sendPOSTwithCHECK() {
    // Сохраним прежнее значение добавив атрибут "data-original-value" 
    //  поместив в него содержимое редактируемой области
    $('.exampleEdit').each(function (i, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        $item.attr('data-original-value', $item.text());
    });

    // ...и понеслись
    $('.exampleEdit').editable( function (value, settings) {

        // Если value... , тогда...
        if (!value) {
            alert('Поле НЕ должно быть пустым!');
            return $(this).data('original-value');       
        } 

        // Если value не ..., тогда "постим" данные на сервер...
        if (value) {

            /* Предварительно логируем необходимые данные в консоль браузера
                console.log($('#yourId').text());
                console.log(value);
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            */

            // отправка...
            $.post("http://site.ru/save.php", { 
                firstVal    : $('#yourId').text(),  // Можно передавать так...
                secondVal   : value,                // Можно так...
                thirdVal    : $(this).attr('id')    // и даже так...
            });

            // вернем новое значение в редактируемую область
            return(value);
        }
    });
}
```

и примерчик... [Код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6WVa/5/)

Comment: а так он эту функцию вызывает как сабмит, для каждого поля ? я просто искал дополнительно способ оставить пользователя в поле редактирования, onsubmit для этого подходит, а для проврки используйте 

    value.match(/^\d+$/) //если я правильно понял - только цифры

Comment: @eicto что-то не работает, мот на фидли подсобите? мой примерчик проапдейтить... пожалуйста! а потом ответом на мой вопрос, а я плюсану по-мужски ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v6WVa/7/

Comment: @eicto ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО, почему не ответом!? Выставляйте ответ!!!

Comment: да нет смысла, ответ у вас по сути.

Comment: @eicto а можно еще вопросик :) ? а как понять вот эту часть кода:

 var $that = $(this),
        original_value = $that.data('original-value');

запятая после this... не понимаю, поясните пожалуйста :)

Comment: объявляю две локальных переменных $that и original_value

---
original_value без $ (я $ обозначаю обычно объекты jquery, чтобы не забыть)